# Visual Studio 2015 Community Diagnostic Tools - No Memory Usage tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, I can see under Diagnostic Tools the session time, Events, Process Memory, CPU Utilisation then tabs for Events, Memory Usage and CPU Usage.

However on another machine, running the Community version on Windows 10, the Process Memory section and Memory Usage tab are missing, as below;

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Community Diagnostic Tools]

Both the options for Memory and CPU Usage were enabled before starting the debugging.

Is this something that isn't available in the Community edition (this suggests it should be? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx) or is it something else?

Comment: Running both in Debug Mode? I certainly see the Memory Usage tab in my version of 2015 Community. Perhaps there is also a difference between running 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Both running 32-bit applications in debug mode... however I've noticed the same solution running on Enterprise also has the Memory tools missing, and creating a new default project on the Community version restores the memory usage tools. After a bit more digging it seems like the Memory tools are only available on projects using .NET 4.0 and newer (I was using .NET 2.0 earlier).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Answer (score 10):

The problem was due to the projects being in .NET 2.0 and had to use .NET 4.0 or newer, rather than an issue of Community vs Enterprise Visual Studio versions.